# Change orientation of a pdf using zend pdf

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation

I have an existing pdf, and i want to load it, change its orientation and save it. I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('mypdf');
$page = $pdf->pages[0];
$page->rotate(0,0,deg2rad(90));
$pdf->save('new.pdf');
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the page `$page` to the PDF document `$pdf` after you rotated the page:

```
$page->rotate(0,0,deg2rad(90));
$pdf->pages[0] = $page; // assign the page to the PDF document
$pdf->save('new.pdf');
```

Be aware that in the above example the old page 1 is overwritten in the `$pdf` object.